# URL filtering using regex : find first instance only of a string, but not when it is prefixed by a particular other string

Tags: regex

I need to be able to identify the first instances of Content within URLs
but not those that contain wwwroot before this first instance.
I do not want it to find any subsequent instances of Content
and need all aspects of it to be case insensitive.

i.e. it needs to find the first content only in these URLs :

```
https://localhost/dfkdfjkdfjkdfkj/Content/dfdfdfdf.png
https://localhost/wwwrootExtra/Content/dfdfdfdf.png
https://localhost/dfkdfjkdfjkdfkj/ConTent/Images/ConTent/Patrol.png
```

and not find any Content instances in these URLs :

```
https://localhost/MangoTrunkDebug/wwwRoot/ConTent/dffddf.png
https://localhost/MangoTrunkDebug/wwwRoot/ConTent/Images/ConTent/Patrol.png
```

I have got at far as this, but now struggling :

```
(?<!(?i)\/wwwroot)\/(?i)Content\/
```

This still selects Contents beyond the first instance.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Of use : 
    https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

You get 2 matches because the assertion `(?<!(?i)\/wwwroot)` is valid in both scenarios.

One option could be to not match `/wwwroot/` or `/Content/` before matching `/Content/` and capture the first occurrence in a capturing group.

You can enable case insensitive in the tool or programming language or add `(?i)` to the pattern.

```
^https?://(?:(?!/(?:wwwroot|Content)/).)*/(Content)/
```

- `^` Start of string
- `https?://` Match the http part
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!/(?:wwwroot|Content)/).)*` Match any char for directly followed by wwwroot or content
- `/(Content)/` Match `/`, capture content in group 1 and match `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yh0u8c/1)

Another option is to make use of a quantifier in the lookbehind [if it is supported](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width).

```
(?<!.*(?:/(?:wwwRoot|ConTent)/.*))(?<=/)Content(?=/)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!.*%28%3f%3a%2f%28%3f%3awwwRoot%7cConTent%29%2f.*%29%29%28%3f%3c%3d%2f%29Content%28%3f%3d%2f%29&i=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fdfkdfjkdfjkdfkj%2fContent%2fdfdfdfdf.png%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fContewwwrootExtra%2fContent%2fdfdfdfdf.png%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fdfkdfjkdfjkdfkj%2fConTent%2fImages%2fConTent%2fPatrol.png%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fMangoTrunkDebug%2fwwwRoot%2fConTent%2fdffddf.png%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fMangoTrunkDebug%2fwwwRoot%2fConTent%2fImages%2fConTent%2fPatrol.png&o=i)